# LEFT JOIN is pulling in NULL values even though AND statement should filter them out

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query with two `LEFT JOIN`. Results are returning `NULL` data that should be filtered out based on the `AND` in the `WHERE` clause. See query below:

```sql
SELECT 
  C.CASE_ID,
  A.PERSON_ID,
  P.NAME
FROM 
  CASE C
LEFT JOIN ATTENDANCE A
  ON C.CASE_ID = A.CASE_ID
    AND A.ROLE IN (1, 2)
LEFT JOIN PERSON P
  ON A.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
    AND PR.POSITION IN (3, 4, 5)
```

The returned results meet the `AND` statement in the first join but should be filtered out based on the `AND` statement in the second join, however it's returning `NULL`s instead.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: LEFT JOIN typically gives NULL values in the result. Try INNER JOIN to avoid them.

Comment: I'm using a left join because the attendence table may be empty for some case records. I added the filters in the AND statement to filter out the unneeded records but they're still comgin in.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: By definition left outer joins will return nulls in the columns of the table that is joined. You can filter out rows using `WHERE`. A predicate added to the `ON` clause becomes a "joining predicate" while a predicate added in the `WHERE` clause becomes a "filtering predicate". Probably you want to use `WHERE`.

Comment: I do not see results, that are present, but should be filtered out. Actually, there're no filters at all.

Comment: @TheImpaler that worked! Thank you. I did not realize the difference in using in the WHERE clause or ON clause. That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: What is `PR` in your second join condition? There is no such alias anywhere in your query. (So, obviously, the query you posted is not the one you ran - why is that?) If it should be `P` instead, and you really need a left outer join to `P`, then you should leave **that** condition where it is (while moving the condition on `A.ROLE` to the `WHERE` clause, as has been suggested already).